# Join table error on running migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models in rails 5.1

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sub_categories, join_table: "categories_join_table"
end

class SubCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, join_table: "categories_join_table"
end
```

I have added multiple migrations the problem is when I try to run migration I get the error `ERROR:  relation "comfort_factor_sub_categories" does not exist` because in the migration to create table comfort_factor_sub_categories will run in later migrations. How can I handle this?
Note: I can't change the name of join_table as it is just an example I have long names.

Comment: Have you done anything different from what it is suggested in guide about it? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#creating-join-tables-for-has-and-belongs-to-many-associations could your share a sample of what you have done in your migrations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is over three years old at the time of this writing, but I just ran into the same problem so I thought I'd share my solution here.

In my case, I was running Rails 6.1, so my error message looked a bit different:

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Could not find table 'officers_users'
```

The `officers_users` table is a join table that is created in a later migration, but the migration in question doesn't make any use of it, so why was I getting this error?

At first, I thought it might be a Rails bug as my migration was using `update_columns` to modify the users table, which shouldn't run any callbacks, but then I noticed that the values that I was updating them with were dependent on a computed attribute, which in turn was dependent on the `officers_users` join table. So Rails was right and I was wrong (once again, hah)! The solution was simply to make the failing migration self-sufficient without needing that computed attribute. Once I did that, everything was good again.

So if you run into the same problem, I would suggest checking your migration with a fine toothed comb and look for any hidden dependencies that might be using the later migration's join table.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you have added several migrations and you cannot run them because some relationship is not found.

In that case, you should [duplicate the classes in migrations](https://railsguides.net/change-data-in-migrations-like-a-boss/#duplicate-classes-in-migrations):

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    # without declaring the relationship with the table which does not exist yet
  end

  def up
    create_table :categories do |t|
      # t.something
    end
  end
  def down
    drop_table :categories
  end
end
```

You should then do the same thing for `SubCategory`.

For creating a proper join_table, you can refer to Rails [official documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#creating-join-tables-for-has-and-belongs-to-many-associations)